# How to Show the SMTP Status

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp

I wrote a program 1 year ago .
I designed a form for "Connect us " . and it was a winform with an Email Textbox and ...etc.

I use SMTP to send an email to my email to understand what they want me to know.

Many of my customers say to me , "I sended an Email for your product " but I don't receive anything !
after that , I understand Some anti viruses are blocking the SMTP and I install an anti virus and block SMTP , then send my email on debug mode but nothing happened (The program doesnt give me any error) .

So ,

1. Is there any programmatically way to understand , Is SMTP blocked or Not ?!
2. I use FTP to send suggest of customers but I know that , It is not a secure way for me and my customers . cause many person use our IIS server as administrator(And Im not admin of this server) . Can U suggest me anything to send my customer suggest in a secure way ?!

Thank U for read .

Comment: *All people lie* (c) Dr.House. You can show a hint to disable antiviruses or you can generate *report* file to be sent to you by using their normal email clients (or web mails).

Comment: @Sinatr All People May lie but me not (c) Dr.Home ... :) Yeah , You are right but you and I know that many people dont set their email to programs like outlook . It is the reason .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the anti-virus products catch it and prevent the SMTP service from sending it, not from you making requests, so I don't think you are going to have any luck programatically determining if it was intercepted.

The easiest option (but not fool proof) is to shell out to Windows with a

> mailto:email@emailaddress.com

I would switch to a web service where you pass the information to your server and your server sends the emails.

Comment: Yeah , U are right but many people dont set their email on (Outlook ) and after see the outlook , Dont send email !!!